# Submit button to update database, won't work if there is postback stated in page_load

Tags: asp.net, webforms, postback, pageload

I have a web form page that I am going to query the data from database via selecting different values from dropdown list, after I selected proper value, in the description I want to update the database record while I click the submit button, for example, customer name, and status, there will be only one record coming back and the description will show(I can do it in `isPostback` and query the database, using SQL DataReader and then call related index element to get it) but when I typed something in the description and click submit, it won't update in the database, but if I don't use `if(isPostback)` it is working. 
P.S. if there is no `if(ispostback)` case block there,`dataUpdate.Update()` works well.
So my question is;

[image]

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{            
   dataUpdate.Update();               
}
```

The page_load code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        ValidationSettings.UnobtrusiveValidationMode = UnobtrusiveValidationMode.None;         

        if (!IsPostBack)
        {              
            SqlConnection conn1 = new SqlConnection(cxInfo.ConnectionString);
            string userInfoQuery1 = "select * from users where id=@id";
            SqlCommand userInfo1 = new SqlCommand(userInfoQuery1, conn1);
            userInfo1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", dropdlCx.SelectedValue);
            conn1.Open();
            SqlDataReader reader1 = userInfo1.ExecuteReader();
            reader1.Read();
            if (reader1.HasRows )
            {
                lblCxId.Text = "" + reader1[0];
                SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(dataUpdate.ConnectionString);
                string userInfoQuery = "select cx_first_name+',' + cx_last_name as 'name',cx_id ,incident_id,description,contact_method from incident where cx_id=@id and status=@status";
                SqlCommand userInfo = new SqlCommand(userInfoQuery, conn);
                userInfo.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", lblCxId.Text);
                userInfo.Parameters.AddWithValue("@status", dropStatus.SelectedValue);
                conn.Open();
                SqlDataReader reader = userInfo.ExecuteReader();
                reader.Read();
                if (reader.HasRows)
                {
                    lblCxId.Text = "" + reader1[0];
                    txtDesc.Text = (string)reader[3];
                    radioContact.SelectedValue = (string)reader[4];
                    desc= (string)reader[3]; 
                }

                conn.Close();
            }

            conn1.Close();
        }
        if (IsPostBack)
        {
            lblCxId.Text = dropdlCx.SelectedValue;
           /*I want to have txtDesc.txt= database query here, but as long as I add the code here, then the update won't work*/              
        }
    }
```

So I think there only thing I got stuck is how to let the system know that what I submit is not the thing that he is going to refresh, please accept my value instead of the refresh?

Comment: Hi, I cannot understand what you want exactly I was road the question three times but still cannot understand what you want. Please trace your code by putting a break point and see whats the values, then update your question and let us understand where is the point of help.

Comment: I have two dropdown list which limit the cretaria of database selection queries, and want the description textbox showing the result  by running sql script select * from table where two limitation from the two dropdown list. the problem is that if I do this for the description textbox, the page _load will keep refreshing the page with the data queried from database, and it won't let me update the information I entered into the text box. if I don't code if ( ispostback ) then every time I change the value in dropdown list won't refresh the description text box. is this better explanation?